# Can a market capitalization of a derivative asset ever be worth more than the underlying instrument?

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics

Is there an example (in history or present-day) of the total market capitalization of a derivative asset being worth more than the market capitalization of the underlying instrument? And would this make sense in any circumstance?

Comment: How do you define market cap of derivs?